# Javascript Regex: clear the CSV

Tags: javascript, regex, csv

I have a CSV of property values of an object, and I need to remove all empty values from it

```
var myObj = { a: "", b: "", c: "c", d: "" };

var result = Object.values(myObj).join(",");
console.log("result before: " + result); // result before: ,,c,

result = result.replace(/(^\,)|(\,$)|\,\,/, "");
console.log("result after: " + result); // result after: ,c,
```

as you can see my regex of custom "trip(,)" does not work very well, where is the error ?

> I need to remove all ",," and trimEnd(,) + trimStart(,)

**PS.**

A) One solution is to filter objects;
  B) Another solution is to fix the regex;

Comment: so you want just `c` at the end? or `{c:"c"}` ?

Comment: yes, remove all empty values

Comment: so the output you want object with keys having non empty values right?

Comment: yes, only non-empty values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a regex solution, join only defined elements.

```
var myObj = { a: "", b: "", c: "c", d: "" };

var result = Object.values(myObj).filter(function(o){
    return o;
}).join(",");
console.log("result before: " + result);
```

Regex solution

```
var myObj = { a: "", b: "", c: "c", d: "" };

var result = Object.values(myObj).join(",");
console.log("result before: " + result); // result before: ,,c,

result = result.replace(/(^\,+)|(\,+$)|(?!\,[^,])(\,|\,\,+)/g, "");
console.log("result after: " + result); // result after: c
```

How it works

```
(^\,+)                            Match any number of commas in the beginning of the string
     |(\,+$)                      Or any number at the end
            |(?!\,[^,])(\,|\,\,+) Or a single, or multiple commas that aren't followed by another character
```

Comment: great solution! I wonder however as well were was the problem in the Regex :)

Comment: I've added a regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the problem, that would be my solution:

```js
const obj = { a: 'a', b: '', c: '', d: 'd' }

const res = Object.keys(obj)
  .reduce((c, e) => obj[e] ? [...c, obj[e]] : c, [])
  .join(',')

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just filter your array in line 2?

```
var result = Object.values(myObj).filter(function (x) {return x!="";}).join(",");
```